# Creating a pkcs#7 object in C with external digital signature

Tags: c, cryptography, digital-signature, pkcs#7, cryptlib

I am using a smart card device used to sign pdf document. I already know how to sign the pdf using itext.

I have a 20 byte sha-1 hash, 256 byte signature (rsa encrypted by smart card private key) and a public key (.cer certificate)

Is there a way to create a pkcs#7 binary object in C, using a free library such as cryptlib?

Comment: Probably, but you would need access to the smart card for private key ops. The old signature is useless. "cryptlib can make use of the crypto capabilities of a variety of external crypto devices such as hardware crypto accelerators, Fortezza cards, PKCS #11 devices, hardware security modules (HSMs), and crypto smart cards. It can be used with a variety of crypto devices that have received FIPS 140 or ITSEC/Common Criteria certification. The crypto device interface also provides a general-purpose plug-in capability for adding new functionality that can be used by cryptlib."

Comment: Note that SHA-1 is not considered secure anymore, especially not for long term signature storage for non-repudiation.

Comment: I already have the signed bytes from the card and the hash of the file. All I have left is to create the PKCS#7 Object. I could not find any where how to programmatically create a PKCS#7 binary object.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to generate a PKCS#7 / CMS (cryptographic message syntax) signature using a pre-calculated signature.

This is - to my surprise - possible but for a very big **IF**. That **IF** is that the CMS message doesn't contain any additional meta data that needs to be signed. [In the badly phrased words of the CMS RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.4):

> ```
> ...
> ```

> ```
> When the signedAttrs field is absent, only the octets comprising the
> ```

```
value of the SignedData encapContentInfo eContent OCTET STRING (e.g.,
the contents of a file) are input to the message digest calculation.
This has the advantage that the length of the content being signed
need not be known in advance of the signature generation process.
```

> ```
> ...
> ```

You can exclude the `signedAtrrs` in for instance [OpenSSL using the  `-noattr` command line option](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Cms(1)). Unfortunately I did not find a direct way to include the signature value itself, but this is very likely to be possible using the C API of OpenSSL - and as OpenSSL is Open Source, it would of course be possible to amend this problem if it isn't.

---

Notes:

- A good hack would be to create a signature over a zero byte value using a different key when performing CMS, then look up that value (by binary search or by parsing the ASN.1 CMS structures) and then replace that signature with the one you've generated;
- CryptLib and SHA-1 are only useful when you are planning to travel back in time. I strongly recommend to use well maintained libraries and - of course - secure hash.

Comment: byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, hashAlgorithm);
 byte[] ocsp = null;
 byte[] extSignature = externalSignature.Sign(sh);
 sgn.SetExternalDigest(extSignature, null, externalSignature.GetEncryptionAlgorithm());

byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash,.., sigtype);
byte[] encodedSig = sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, tsaClient, ocsp, crlBytes, sigtype);

I  wrote all the steps in C except GetEncodedPKCS7 method. This method requires only 3 arguments: the hash bytes, the external signatures bytes and the *.cer certificate. Is there a way to implement GetEncodedPKCS7 in C?